# Connecting wind generator to 12V battery without regulator

Tags: power-electronics, energy-harvesting

I've been doing a DIY  Wind energy generator. I'm also a newbie in this field. I would like to ask what will happen if I connect my wind turbine to a 12V rechargeable battery without a voltage regulator?

Comment: Poof, sizzle, explode, and combust are words that come to mind

Comment: You didn't even specify the battery chemistry and type. Bad idea, you have to learn a lot before you have chances of completing this safely.

Comment: If your generator is small enough, the battery may spin the generator, or at least discharge through its coils.

Comment: If the generator was a 12v car alternator with regulator, yes. Otherwise **HELL NO!**

Comment: It can't be said enough: **DO NOT** work with batteries unless you absolutely know what you are doing. **ALWAYS** incorporate a fuse, as most batteries will discharge with extremely high currents when short-circuited.

Answer (score 6):

Don't let this happen to you:

[image]
[image]

Batteries don't like excessive voltage or current and will destroy themselves and injure others if proper steps are not taken to ensure these conditions do not occur. For these reasons it is very important that the charger you use is suitable to the battery. Remember,

### Battery acid can blind or disable you.

### Electricity can injure or kill you.

Please do research on battery and electrical safety to ensure these things do not happen to you. If you are determined to do DIY projects like this, follow the instructions exactly and make sure you trust the instructor enough that you can feel confident you won't be injured. In any case of uncertainty, ask before you try!

Comment: I'll add that batteries of any chemistry contain enough aggressive substances that can cause similar damage if anything goes wrong.

Comment: That's true, and even if the battery doesn't contain toxic substances, it is simply used to store energy. Put too much energy in, and that energy has to come out somehow. That "somehow" is determined by several factors, and is almost always very very bad.

Comment: Well, toxicity importance is overestimated. For example, sulphuric acid (used in lead-acid batteries) is definitely not the most toxic thing in the world, it does its damage by simply burning through stuff, human flesh included.

Comment: hi.. thanks for your response.. reading your answers and comments scares the hell out of me.. good thing i found this site.. thanks for the answers guys..

Comment: @john, glad to hear that, I was considering using more graphic pictures, but you got the message! Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks.. I got one more question though.. how about connecting my generator to dc12v to ac220v power inverter? will this also burn/explode the inverter??

Comment: @john: That should actually be a separate question.

Comment: Aww, you should have used [this picture](http://www.thebeerdrifter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/melting-man.jpg).